# tkinter: scrollbar autohide without window resize

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.5

Using the folowing sample code I wrote I am having issues with some behavior.
I want to add/remove the scrollbar as needed. But when I do it shifts all other elements in the window as the window resizes. This is just a sample to demonstrate the issue, you will see the window resize when the scrollbar is added and removed. In the real application there are more widgets on the window.

Am I trying to do this the right way or if not how can I resolve the issue? I also plan to have a second widget with scrollbars as well in another separate frame.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class TopFrame(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, col=0, row=0):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.innerframe = ttk.Frame(parent)

        self.list_scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(self.innerframe)
        self.list_scroll.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=NS)
        self.list_scroll.grid_remove()

        self.list = Listbox(self.innerframe, width=64, height=8,
                            yscrollcommand=self.list_scroll.set)
        self.list_scroll.config(command=self.list.yview)
        self.list.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NSEW)

        self.innerframe.grid(column=col, row=row)

        self.addbtn = ttk.Button(parent, text='add item',
                                 command=self.additem)
        self.addbtn.grid(column=col, row=row+1, padx=10, pady=2)
        self.delbtn = ttk.Button(parent, text='del item',
                                 command=self.delitem)
        self.delbtn.grid(column=col, row=row+2, padx=10, pady=2)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def additem(self):
        count = str(len(self.list.get(0, END)))
        self.list.insert(END, 'demo' + count)
        if len(self.list.get(0, END)) > 8:
            self.list_scroll.grid()

    def delitem(self):
        self.list.delete(END)
        if len(self.list.get(0, END)) <= 8:
            self.list_scroll.grid_remove()

class MasterFrame(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        topframe = TopFrame(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MasterFrame().mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the window has been displayed for the first time you can get the window size, and then use that to call the `geometry` method on the root window. When you set the size of the window with the `geometry` command it will stop resizing based on changes to its internal widgets.

The simplest thing is to write a function to do that, and schedule it to run with `after_idle`, which should fire after the window is first displayed.